# HTTParty. Catch auth error before response is parsed with JSON/XML parser

Tags: ruby, httparty

With HTTParty I've come across a situation when I cannot correctly catch the auth error because the JSON or XML parser intercepts the "HTTP Basic: Access denied." response.

Here's my code:

require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

```
class Client
  include HTTParty
  def initialize(host, user, password)
    self.class.base_uri host
    self.class.basic_auth user, password
  end

  def get(base_path, data_format)
    self.class.get("#{base_path}.#{data_format}")
  end
end

cl = Client.new('host.com', 'useranme', 'password')
p cl.get('/resource_path', 'json')
```

Runnig this, if username or password is wrong, I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/ayurchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse': 743: unexpected token at 'HTTP Basic: Access denied. (MultiJson::DecodeError)
'
    from /home/ayurchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
    from /home/ayurchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@uitests/gems/multi_json-1.0.4/lib/multi_json/engines/json_common.rb:9:in `decode'
    from /home/ayurchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@uitests/gems/multi_json-1.0.4/lib/multi_json.rb:76:in `decode'
    from /home/ayurchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@uitests/gems/httparty-0.8.1/lib/httparty/parser.rb:116:in `json'
    from /home/ayurchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@uitests/gems/httparty-0.8.1/lib/httparty/parser.rb:136:in `parse_supported_format'
    ...
```

Is there any possible way to catch those auth errors before the parser gets the response?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the most desirable solution, but you could monkey patch it quickly enough. The error comes out of HTTParty's Parser class, which calls unsafe methods on MultiJson without dealing with possible errors.

I just dropped the following in an initializer, which allows me to move inspect these responses, looking for the 401 status code, which is really all you need.

```
module HTTParty
  class Parser
    protected
    def json
      if MultiJson.respond_to?(:adapter)
        MultiJson.load(body) rescue {}
      else
        MultiJson.decode(body) rescue {}
      end
    end
  end
end
```